# Polyfit issue with vector sizes even though size() function shows they're the same

Tags: matlab

I am receiving this error message, but I've printed the size of my two vectors and they're identical. I'm not sure what else could be causing it

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to `polyfit` should be a number indicating the degree of the polynomial.  You've given it a string, which is confusing it.  If you want a linear fit, use `polyfit(x, y, 1)`.